# Are std::malloc/calloc/realloc/free any different from pure C's malloc/calloc/realloc/free

Tags: c++, c, malloc

Why C++ needed its own versions of C's standard library malloc/calloc/realloc/free functions? They all seem completely identical. Should I prefer to use std:: versions in C++? Can they behave differently?

Comment: They are identical, C++ simply puts the C functions into the C++ `std` namespace. Though, you really shouldn't be using them in C++ at all, there are better/safer ways to manage memory in C++.

Comment: you should read up on namespaces and why they are used. Thats basically the only difference.

Comment: In C++ you shouldn't need them except for when writing code interfacing with C libraries, and even then, selectively. `new` and `delete` are the C++ ways of allocating and releasing memory.

Comment: Who knows. They are different languages and can be implemented differently. You have no guarantee at all. You need to ask people who wrote the standard library for your toolchain

Comment: If you want to use standard C functions in C++, you must find them in the `std` namespace. All of C++ standard library is inside `namespace std`; dropping that namespace is generally wrong(except maybe due to ADL). There's no guarantee that standard  C functions are available in global namespace; In fact, the ideal implementations is not to have any trace of them in global namespace.

Comment: I know that in C++ its preferable to use use new/delete or even smart pointers for memory management. But that just adds up into why they needed to redefine seemingly discouraged functions used only for interfacing with C in std, no?

Comment: Even in C++ every now and then you will find yourself writing a bit of low-level code to handle the plumbing. That's when `std::malloc` and friends come out of the toolbox. The `std` versions of some functions are a little different, for example there's a nifty template wrapper in `std::pow` that ultimately calls `pow`. Not seeing anything like that for `std::malloc`, though.

Comment: @user4581301 where do you see it? Is there some github repository for that to look around actual implementations?

Comment: A lot can be seen inside the c-prefixed header files that came with the library implementation. But yeah, lots of this stuff is easily accessible online. For example googling *github gcc* popped this up: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why C++ needed its own versions of C's standard library malloc/calloc/realloc/free functions?

The reason for C++ including most of C library is cross-compatibility. Especially during early days of C++, it was important that C programs could easily be incrementally converted to C++.

A big problem in C is name collisions. C++ introduced a language feature to mitigate this problem: namespaces. The C++ standard library is in the namespace `std`. Due to the a fore mentioned cross-compatiblity, the C++ standard library declares the C-inherited names in the global namespace when C-inherited headers are included using the names they have in the C standard library (such as `<stdlib.h>`).

> Can they behave differently?

No. They are the same functions in a different namespace.

> malloc/calloc/realloc/free
>
> Should I prefer to use std:: versions in C++?

You should prefer to not use any of the mentioned functions in C++. You almost never need them. A rare reason to use them is when you're incrementally re-writing a C program in C++, and you don't want to replace all of the old code in one change. Sometimes you might need to use `std::free` if you need to use a C library that requires it.

There are parts of C standard library other than the functions that you mentioned that don't have a new replacement in C++. In such case, include the header<sup>1</sup> using the C++ alternative name (such as `<cstdlib>`), and refer to the names in the `std` namespace.

<sup>1</sup> Or even better in C++23, don't include a header at all, but `import std;` instead.

Comment: Thank you! So all C standard library (with rare exeptions as I understand from your answer) is redefined in C++ std library? I didn't know that.

Comment: @simd - It doesn't have to be totally "redefined", as `namespace std { using ::malloc; }` will do for getting `malloc` into the namespace.

Comment: "A big problem in C is name collisions. " It is not a problem when it comes to library functions specifically - C clearly states that names of library functions are reserved for the library. So `std::` is not the solution to that non-existent problem in the C standard library. Rather "everything C" just ends up in the `std` namespace because the C libs too are part of the C++ standard library. It has nothing to do with namespace collisions.

Answer (score 1):

> Why C++ needed its own versions of C's standard library malloc/calloc/realloc/free functions? They all seem completely identical. Should I prefer to use std:: versions in C++? Can they behave differently?

Nope.  You are wrong.  There are not different versions of `malloc()`, etc. functions for use in C++.  Even the header files are the same (you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to use them, as in C)

The functions indeed belong to the world of C, and their use is not only deprecated and not recommended use, because the C++ runtime has it's memory allocation operators `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`.  These are typesafe and allow memory allocation implementors to structure allocation and use of multiple heaps (e.g. in which different types get allocated from different pools)  Yet Stroustrups discourages in his book the use of *superseeded* C functions in C++.

But this doesn't mean that the versions you see differently (e.g. `printf` is seen from C++ as `std::printf`, in the `std` namespace) are indeed different.   They appear to be in `std` namespace, to allow you to write your own versions in your own namespaces.  Namespaces are not supported in C.  C++ was designed to be able to get profit of the already written C library, and the success of this subproject has added a lot of complexity to the C++ language.  Not in vain.  Any function written for C is automatically usable in C++.  And this explains the fact that the functions you are actually using have not been rewritten in C++ (they have also been discouraged) for easy of use (once you get used to object oriented programming, the new repacements cited above are more type safe and easier to use)